# Fill up DataGrid with empty rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable`. I want the `DataGrid` to always have at least ten (empty) rows, also if there are not enough real data-items (the data comes in little by little).
[image: Example]

One approach would be to easily add ten empty rows to the `DataTable` at initialization. But when a real data-item comes in, I can't easily add the row, I have to find the first empty row to overwrite it, what is not very handy.
So someone knows a smarter/built-in way to achieve this?

Comment: How about just adding empty items to your collection if the `Count` of the collection is less than 10?

Comment: That's what I said, I always have to check how many real rows there are, and add or delete the empty rows. I hoped there would be a smarter or built-in approach.

Comment: Why do you need to delete rows? Also you don't need to overwrite existing ones, just rebind the whole collection if next time the count is greater than 10.

Comment: Ok, I guess you want to add the empty rows directly to the datagrid, not to the datatable. But that doesn't work, you either can bind the datagrid OR add manually items, but not both.

Comment: Do you use one-way binding? From your MV/Object to DataGrid?

Comment: I only say `dataGrid.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataTable);`. I think, that should be one-way binding.

Comment: What is so hard or messy about looking for the first empty row and replacing it if the count is 10 else add a row?

Comment: @BalamBalam Likely you are right, seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Consider looking at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890890/how-to-fill-up-datagrid-with-empty-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's gonna be mess, no matter from what side it's approached. I'd say your best bet (provided that your grid cells content won't be wrapped) is to use a visual brush (with lines) as your DataGrid's background.

UPDATE 1 - XAML
It's alwast there, the trick is to use MinHeight, which will produce a vision of blank items thanks to tiled background. If your grid will be populated with the real data the background will expand, rendering more lines.

One thing I didn't try is how it'll handling scrolling.

Here's an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="StripesBrush" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,5,20"
               Viewbox="0,0,10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
               ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Line X1="0" X2="10000" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="DarkGray"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="g" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              GridLinesVisibility="None" 
              MinHeight="100"
              Height="100"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Background="{StaticResource StripesBrush}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Item1}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Item2}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach, but looks very faked in comparison to a real datagrid. Also the column-lines are missing.

Comment: @SpeziFish Cheers, it's a quick an nasty way to get things done.

Answer (score 0):

if its just for layout, you can simply add a second datagrid with 10 empty rows under your real datagrid. or you take the aproach Dmitry posted and use visual brush

Comment: but you dont have to manipulate your real data and all can be done in xaml;)