# WPF DataGrid verticalGridLine does not appear till the end

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am using `WPF DataGrid`. On that i need vertical grid lines permanently till the end even it does not contains any rows. but its showing vertical line up to the rows its contains.

Could any of you please suggest any idea to achieve that...?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the visibility of the grid lines with GridLinesVisibility.

```
<DataGrid ...
      GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"/>
```

Comment: if it has two rows, it shows line till two rows. if three rows, it shows till three rows. but i need vertical line till the end of the data grid, if it contains any number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way or support from Microsoft to achieve this.

However you may consider this,

[Fill up DataGrid with empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254736/fill-up-datagrid-with-empty-rows)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44622c0-74e1-463b-97b9-27b87513747e/windows-forms-data-controls-and-databinding-faq?forum=winformsdatacontrols#faq13

(Hardcored Approach)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks arun, i got some ides to achieve this from your post.