# How do I make the vertical gridlines of DataGrid go to the bottom of the DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with some rows inside, and I'd like to have the vertical lines go to the bottom of the `DataGrid`.

[image]

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the visibility of the grid lines with GridLinesVisibility.

```
<DataGrid...
      GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"/>
```

Or you can fill it up using empty rows:
[Fill up DataGrid with empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254736/fill-up-datagrid-with-empty-rows)

Comment: `GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"` will only deactivate the rendering of horizontal lines, but not extend the vertical ones.  And if possible, I'd like to try to not mess with my data.