# How can I make the lines between the columns in the data grid high as the data grid height?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am a completely newbie in WPF and I am struggling with the below issue.
I am having a problem with the lines between the columns in the data grid. 
The lines only appear as long as I have some data load into the data grid. I would like to make the lines as high as the data grid in order to have a nice UI( if I don't have any data loaded, I want to still have the lines between the columns) . Can you please help?

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254736/fill-up-datagrid-with-empty-rows

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the height to the grid\columns in it. Set it to 100% or as per the data grid height, then you will get the column lines visible for the same as the data grid.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But how can I set the height to the column? In <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> I only have the width parameter. Can you provide me an example?

Comment: The following code sets height and width of data grid.

<DataGrid Height="200" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,21,0,0" Name="TestDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="30" ColumnWidth="100">

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourDataSourceCollection}" HeadersVisibility="Column" Background="LightGray" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Name And Time" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource headerStyle}" Width="150" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IsMale" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource headerStyle}" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked={Binding IsMale,Mode=TwoWay}/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
   ........
   .........
</DataGrid>`
```